# Proxied FactoryBean implementation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scope

I want to implement `FactoryBean` interface to initialize my bean. But I want to inject proxy objects to my services.

```
@Configuration
public class SomeContextFactory implements FactoryBean<SomeClass>
{
  //implementation
}
```

How should I change this code for proxied objects? (Spring boot, no xml)

I need to dynamically generate objects by `getObject()` and inject those objects to some singleton service.

Additional: With my custom scope (or prototype scope)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?  Add more details. (i.e. proxy object, service etc ..)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `SomeClass` and `SomeContextFactory`:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private int id;

// Setter
// Getter
// All args contructor
}


public class SomeContextFactory implements FactoryBean<SomeClass>
{
    private int someClassId;
 
    @Override
    public SomeClass getObject() throws Exception {
        return new SomeClass(someClassId);
    }
 
    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return SomeClass.class;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true; // for singleton scope
    }

  //  @Override
  //  public boolean isPrototype() {
  //     return true; // for prototype scope
  // }


// Setter
// Getter

}
```

Now, you have to tell `spring-boot` about the `FactoryBean`:

```
@Configuration
public class FactoryBeanAppConfig {
  
    @Bean
    public SomeContextFactory someContextFactory() {
        SomeContextFactory factory = new SomeContextFactory();
        factory.someClassId(5);
        return factory;
    }
 
    @Bean
    public SomeClass someClass() throws Exception {
        return someContextFactory().getObject();
    }
}
```

And finally, your Bean `SomeClass` is ready for injection:

```
@Service
public class SomeService implements ISomeService{

@Autowired 
private SomeClass someClass;

public void useSomeClassAndPerformAction(){
 // implementation...
 }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with prototype scope?

Comment: Yes: replace isSingleton() by isProtoype() returning true 
@Override
  public boolean isPrototype() {
         return true; // for prototype scope
      }

Comment: But SomeClass is not proxied

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by proxied? What's your need exactly?